# ListItem click not working in fragment in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am working on a demo application and have used fragments in this demo,I have a listView with custom listItem in this listView,I want to capture the listItem's click event,I have tried lot many ways but nothing is happening,can anybuddy tell me whats wrong with my code,my code is as below:
**xml**
*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<one.tusk.stush.views.PostListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#ffffff" >
        <View android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/goodThing"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLikes"/>
        <one.tusk.stush.views.PostGridItem
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPostImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:contentDescription="Post image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/loadingPost"
         />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profilelist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageViewPostImage"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageViewPostImage"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageViewPostImage"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/photorelative"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewUserImage"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                    android:contentDescription="User image"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:maxWidth="30dp"
                    android:minHeight="30dp"
                    android:minWidth="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar_overlay1" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonComment"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonLike"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_comment" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="37dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/more" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLike"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonShare"
                android:background="@null" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="ss"
                android:textColor="#0c5d55"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPostText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profilelist"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/commentandlike"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewPostText">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numbercomment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLikes"
                android:text="11111"
                android:textColor="#9f9f9f"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLikes"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Likes"
                android:textColor="#9f9f9f"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTimeAgo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

                android:text="aggooooo"
                 android:textColor="#9f9f9f"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
            <View android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLikes"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</one.tusk.stush.views.PostListItem>
```

*

```
public class TimelineFragment extends BaseFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Post>>, OnRefreshListener, OnScrollListener,OnItemClickListener {

    public static ListView mListViewTimeline;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        total = 0;
        mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).allChildrenArePullable().listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        mProgressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
        mTextViewNoItems = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewNoItems);

        mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());

        mListViewTimeline = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeline);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);
        mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);

        mListViewTimeline.setOnScrollListener(this);

        //  mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        mListViewTimeline.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        mListViewTimeline.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        if(activity != null) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    //Do something after 100ms
                }
            }, 1000);



            mTextViewNoItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);

                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    Log.d("CLICK", "REFRESH");

                }
            });
        }

    }
@Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intentPostDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailActivity.class);
        Post post = mTimelineAdapter.getItem(position);
        intentPostDetail.putExtra("Post", post);
        startActivity(intentPostDetail);
    }
}

**timelineadapter**

package one.tusk.stush.adapters;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.company.stush.R;
import one.tusk.stush.connect.Post;
import one.tusk.stush.views.PostListItem;

public class TimelineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TimelineAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_item_post);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setData(List<Post> data) {
        setNotifyOnChange(false); 
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Post post = getItem(position);
        PostListItem view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view =  (PostListItem) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = (PostListItem) convertView;
        }
        view.setPost(post);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any button or clickable item in TimelineAdapter

Comment: Where are you inflating your layout??

Comment: do you get any error or  the itemclicklistener is not working?

Comment: can you post your your xml layout also?

Comment: @saeed-ok.pls see my edit.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" add it your  root layout of row specifaying layout

Comment: means in my listView?i have to put this line?

Comment: the above xml layout is specifying single row of the list view? then you added this android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants " in rootlayout

Comment: can you add timeline adapter also

Comment: @deepak-sure pls see my edit

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intentPostDetail = new Intent(getActivity(), PostDetailActivity.class);
        Post post = mTimelineAdapter.getItem(position);
        intentPostDetail.putExtra("Post", post);
        startActivity(intentPostDetail);
    }
```

try this

```
 mListViewTimeline.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

// do stuff here
}
});
```

Comment: remove  mListViewTimeline.etOnItemClickListener(this);